# Is it possible to validate an HTML file on local disk?

Tags: html, winforms

I was wondering if there is a way to validate an HTML *file residing on disk* using a free service. For example, the windows forms application would call a service with the file information, then the service performs the validation and sends back a result to the client. By validation, I mean syntax checking. The W3C Validator requires the url to start like: https:\www.... and wont accept 
"file:///C:/Users/Owner/..." for example.

Is there such a service?

Is there a similar service (that could also be called from Windows Forms) to format HTML text?

Answer (score 1):

[W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/) apart from URL option has also 2 other.

You can [upload a file](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload) or [directly](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) put the HTML to be tested. Your service should use one of those two and then get back the results and pas them down to the WinForms application.

[W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/) apart from URL option has also 2 other.

You can [upload a file](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload) or [directly](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) put the HTML to be tested. Your service should use one of those two and then get back the results and pass them down to the WinForms application.

```
string htmlToCheck = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>non empty</title></head></html>";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36");
using (var data = new MultipartFormDataContent("------WebKitFormBoundary"))
{
      using (var html = new StringContent(htmlToCheck))
      using (var prefill = new StringContent("0"))
      using (var doctype = new StringContent("inline"))
      using (var prefill_doctype = new StringContent("html401"))
      using (var group = new StringContent("0"))
      {
           data.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data");
           data.Add(html, "fragment");
           data.Add(prefill, "prefill");
           data.Add(doctype, "doctype");
           data.Add(prefill_doctype, "prefill_doctype");
           data.Add(group, "group");
           var result = await client.PostAsync("https://validator.w3.org/nu/", data);
           Console.WriteLine(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }
    }
```

To get the actuall validation result you need to parse th response HTML.

Comment: You are correct. I was wondering if you have an idea on how to call the service from C#? I looked at the documentation but did not grasp a thing!

Comment: @NoChance just do a normal HTTP request to the W3C service with the necessary data.

Comment: I'll add an example later today how to do it

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I think it is rather a complex thing.